# Node command not working in git bash terminal on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, git-bash

I'm trying to run the `node` command in my git bash terminal. When I run the `node` command, nothing happens when I press enter. The `$` goes away and it just leaves a blinking cursor on the next line without the `>`.

```
My-PC MINGW32 /
$ node -v
v4.5.0

My-PC MINGW32 /
$ where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

My-PC MINGW32 /
$ node
_
```

Could someone tell me what the issue could be?

Thanks!!

Comment: when you type node, it usually waits for you type javascript code. Did you tried it?

Comment: What you are seeing is the [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html). It's the expected behaviour. If you pass `node` a file or a directory on the command line it will run that; otherwise, you get the REPL.

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva Yes, I ran a simple ``console.log('hello');`` and it returned nothing.

Comment: @cartant Thanks for the info!

Comment: Watch out for installing ruby together with MSYS2 on Windows also.

Answer (score 19):

If you're not getting a new line with a `>` after entering "node" - this is probably because newer versions of Git Bash don't run in the TTY mode they used to. [Discussion here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3006). You can verify by entering:

```
node -p -e "Boolean(process.stdout.isTTY)"
```

If that returns false - then the Node REPL (and some other console tools) won't work correctly.

There are a couple workarounds:

## Workaround A

```
winpty node
```

Or you can add an alias in your .bash_profile:

```
alias node="winpty node"

# and for npm CLI/scripts:
alias npm="winpty npm.cmd"
```

## Workaround B

Create a new shortcut to Git Bash with the following Target:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i
```

and use that instead of the default Git Bash.

Comment: Oh you have no idea how happy you have just made me!

Comment: how does the workaround B work? what does these option do?  I could not find any manual online about these

Comment: Workaround B runs Git-bash in CMD mode, using the CMD terminal included with windows.  I was having trouble running node programs in git-bash until I ran them in the git-cmd terminal.  I subsequently uninstalled git and re-installed it specifying default use of the cmd terminal by default instead of msys2.  Then I wrap the git-bash terminal in ConEmu for tabs, etc.:  https://conemu.github.io/en/GitForWindows.html   It's the best of both worlds as far as I can tell right now.  I'm on 1809 so I haven't tried the new Windows Terminal yet.

Comment: Also, for a full list of command flags, try this:   /c/program\ files/git/bin/bash -c "help set"